# Google Data Studio connector: Running a promise?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am trying to setup a custom Google Data Studio connector.

In the "getData" call I need to run two api calls before I return the data. I have been told that using a javascript promise is the best way to achieve this.

How do I get the 'GetData' method to only return after the promise has been completed? Is this possible?

Here is the example of the promise:

```
    function getData(request) {
      var apiRequest1 = fetch('www.domain.com/api1').then(function(response){ 
             return response.json()
    });
    var apiRequest2 = fetch('www.domain.com/api2').then(function(response){
             return response.json()
    });
    
    var combinedData = {"apiRequest1":{},"apiRequest2":{}};
    Promise.all([apiRequest1,apiRequest2]).then(function(values){
        combinedData["apiRequest1"] = values[0];
        combinedData["apiRequest2"] = values[1];
        console.log("combined2"+JSON.stringify(combinedData))
        return combinedData;
    
    }

 requestedSchema.forEach(function(field) {
    switch (field.name) {
      case 'weburl':
        var urltoTest = request.configParams.urlTotest;
        values.push(urltoTest);
        break;
      case 'pageSpeed':
        var pageSpeed = parsedResponse.ruleGroups.SPEED.score;
        values.push(pageSpeed);
        break;
      default:
        values.push('');
        break;
    }
  });
```

Comment: "*run two api calls before I return the data*" - that's not possible, you cannot immediately return the result of an asynchronous call. "*I have been told that using a javascript promise is the best way to achieve this.*" - promises allow you to return a promise for the async result, they don't make anything synchronous.

Comment: You will want to put the `var combinedData = {…}` and the `requestedSchema.forEach(function(field) {…` call inside the `then` callback on `Promise.all(…)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way to get this to work nicely is to do both fetches one after each other.

Its not ideal - but hopefully Google will improve this for Data Studio Connectors

Comment: Apps Script does not support async calls. You could try creating a Cloud Function and calling that cloud function from your connector.

Comment: Thanks ! - I will try that approach ! @MinhazKazi - I haven't tried out using a Cloud function from Connectors - are there any good demos anywhere?